# Use image path from postgres, to send image to front-end

Tags: postgresql, image, express, vue.js

I am trying to send images to front-end (Vuejs) using a path stored in postgres.I'am using express.
First, I want to know if it's the right way to send images to the front.

app.js

```
const app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const db = require('./queries');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, '../assets');
console.log("DIR", dir);

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        message: `Hello you get that`
    })
})

app.get('/games', db.getGames)
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)
```

queries.js

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'TTTT',
  password: 'XXXX!',
  port: 5432,
})

const getGames = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY name ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}
module.exports = {
  getGames
}
```

DB :

[image: DB settings]

To sum up, I want to use the path in "img" to serve it to the front.
I hope I've been clear enough. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Ok, I tried express.static( https://expressjs.com/fr/starter/static-files.html ) :
In app.js : app.use('/static', express.static(dir)).
and in front end I access the image using the url of my server followed by '/static' followed by the image url i've stored in my db
Something like "http://localhost:8080/static/persona.jpg" in the src of an img tag for exemple.
Hope it'll help